# Получить данные, если значение 2-х столбцов одинаковые, но находятся на разных строках

Tags: sql

С помощью какого запроса можно получить id и start_date, при условии, что у id есть идентичное значение в столбце return_id?

[image: пример таблицы БД]

Comment: Предалагаю вам раскрыть вопрос. Какая у вас СУБД? Что хочется получить в результате?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть два варианта - соединение и подзапрос.

## 1. Соединение

```sql
select 
    t1.id, 
    t1.start_date
from
    table as t1 
    inner join 
    table as t2 
    on t1.id = t2.return_id
```

## 2. Подзапрос

```sql
select 
    t1.id, 
    t1.start_date
from
    table as t1 
where
    exists (
        select *
        from
            table as t2
        where 
            t2.return_id = t1.id
    )
```

Первый вариант должен быть более оптимальным в плане производительности, так как соединение выполняется только один раз, а подзапрос по каждой строке

Comment: спасибо, все получилось